# Azure DevOps Error within visual studio 2019

Tags: git, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019

This problem started to happen when I updated the version of visual studio 2019 to the most current at the time '16.8.3 'after updating some projects developed with WindowsForms when the solution was opened and we opened the git history this message appears.[the image refers to the azure error that causes the problem of viewing git history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wphq4.png)

Comment: Don't link to an image, just copy the error text into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of researching the error I found someone who had the same problem a few days before me, and managed to resolve using [this link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Git-View-History-fails-with-fatal-error/1266043) thanks for all the help and comments you have posted here.

Comment: The link is dead :(

Comment: Quick solution for this is to open Git GUI in the directory whose history does not appear and compress the database.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following items:

1. Go to web portal, to see whether you can access the git history.
2. If you can access the git history, check whether you use the same account to access the server in VS.
3. Close all Visual Studio instances, delete %LOCALAPPDATA%.IdentityService.
4. Clear Azure Devops server caches %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Cache.
   Re-launch the VS and try to connect to server again.

Comment: these steps didn’t solve it, I had already formatted my computer and also used other accounts, but the error continues.

Comment: Is this issue happen on a particular repo or all repos? Check the solution in this case https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1266043/git-view-history-fails-with-fatal-error.html: Open the repository in Git GUI and compress the database to see whether the issue can be solved.

Comment: After days of researching the error I found someone who had the same problem a few days before me, and managed to resolve
"https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/1282836/view.html"

thanks for all the help and comments you have posted here.